# Closing Driver after all test are runned

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm using Nunit + .NetCore 2.2 in my project and I need to close the browser only after running all the tests and not after each test class. Currently the tests are closing the browser after each test class.
I have many test classes with [Test], but I'm not using [TestFixture].

My class with [OneTimeSetup] is:

```
    public class TestBase
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {

    }


    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {

    }

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetUp()
    {
        DriverFactory.CreateInstance();
        DriverFactory.INSTANCE.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com.br");
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void OneTimeTearDown()
    {
        DriverFactory.QuitInstace();
    }
}
```

And a test class

```
namespace Tests
{
    public class Tests : TestBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void SearchTests()
        {
            SearchPageObjects searchPageObjects = new SearchPageObjects();

            searchPageObjects.PreencherBuscar("Tempo em BH");
            Assert.IsTrue(searchPageObjects.VerificaNomeCidade("Belo Horizonte, MG"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This Question is similar to [Specflow - Close browser after all tests are done
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946175/specflow-close-browser-after-all-tests-are-done) try the solution provided in it.

Comment: Have you read the documenation, you need the SetUpFixutre attribute on the top of your class. [link](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute) and [link](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUp-and-TearDown).TestFixture attribute marks a class that contains tests - [link](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute).

Comment: @HimanilGupta The provided answer is for Specflow Hooks, the OP is asking about NUnit.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a globally accessible driver in your base class and set the driver once in your `OneTimeSetup` method. Make sure you're only closing or quitting the driver in the `OneTimeTearDown` method. In each PageObject class, just pass the driver you created earlier and use `driver.Url = "{url}"` or `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("{Url}")` before any other actions.

If you find that OneTimeSetup is running more than once for some mysterious reason, I would try adding a `bool` variable that checks if it has been run, and if it has then don't do anything. (like the top answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087959/junit-run-set-up-method-once).